# how understand authentication log events on windows 2003

Tags: windows-server-2003, active-directory

How can I understand from log events if a user has connected to the remote desktop and when ?
I have an AD 2003 environment and I would like to know when a certain user has connect to remote desktop service.

Comment: Remote desktop service of the DC? Or of another server?

Comment: it's another server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the Domain Controller(s), configure the Policy: `Policies > Windows Settings > Security Settings > Local Policies > Audit Policy >Audit account logon events` to `Enabled, Success`. Do this with a group policy object assigned to the Domain Controllers organization unit of the domain.

Once the DCs have updated their policy (you can force them with `gpupdate`) an event will be generated in the Security log for every successful logon. Within the event, it will list the Account Name (ie, the username), along with the Source Network Address (IP of the workstation). It will sometimes fill in additional fields depending on the logon type, but those two are reliable.